# citrix desktop mode from seamless mode

Tags: citrix, desktop, seamless

There is one client who is using citrix xenapp and citrix online plugin V11. They are using citrix in seamless mode. Can we change seamless mode to desktop mode somehow? What is the procedure for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - just publish a desktop, rather than an application.

The user will get access to the XenApp server's desktop, with all the installed applications.

Also, Online Plugin v. 11 is several major versions behind and completely unsupported. I would strongly consider upgrading to Receiver 4.4 (aka. version 14.4).